# RestKit .20 with CoreData - How to set default values

Tags: restkit, restkit-0.20

I am using RestKit .20 with CoreData. I have RestKit calling the JSON API successfully and storing the response to the CoreData model without any issues.

My question is how do I set default values at mapping time that are not on the response?

In my situation, I am downloading a list of Alerts to an alert inbox. I need to show which alerts have been read on the local device. I have a CoreData attribute on the entity model called AlertRead (boolean)which I update when the user marks the Alert as 1=read.

My question is how do I set the default value of the attribute to 0=unread at the time the data is retrieved and mapped.

I tried to set the default value in the xcdatamodeld file and this did not work. It appears RestKit sets the value to Nil at mapping time.

One point of clarification..I do not think I want to set this attribute by mapping the attribute to a value on the api because the refresh of the data would override the current data on the local database.

Current code for mapping.

```
RKEntityMapping* alertMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"AlertMessage" inManagedObjectStore:_managedObjectStore];
    [alertMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
     @"alertSubject": @"subject",
     @"alertDetailMessage": @"detailMessage",
     @"id": @"alertId",
     }];
```

Thanks for any suggestions.
G

Answer (score 0):

Look at using [KVC validation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/Validation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002173-CJBDBHCB) (which [RestKit utilises heavily](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Object-mapping#key-value-validation)) to verify the incoming data from RestKit and rejecting the update if it isn't appropriate. This should be used in conjunction with default values set in the `xcdatamodel`.